# How to deploy web app (Spring MVC, JPA,Oracle) on cloud?

Tags: spring-mvc, oracle11g, cloud

I would like to deploy web app on Cloud (Which is built on using Spring MVC Farmework,JPA & Oracle ).Could any one suggest me the best way to deploy it on cloud?.

Vijay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your comment that you're happy to move to a MySQL database, then I'd suggest [Jelastic](http://jelastic.com/), which has the easiest deployment for your stack.  It also has a free trial.

Alternatively, [AppFog](http://appfog.com) is also great, and free for up to 2GB of RAM.

Comment: Your answer helped me lot!! Thanks!! Now i have deployed on Jelastic but there is a problem i could nt upload images(in my application all the images will be loaded on local hard drive) or some index files.

Comment: I'm glad the answer helped.  Please accept the answer, and then ask another question for your issue with images.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to first pick your cloud provider.

Given the technology stack, you may be able to deploy to the Oracle Public Java cloud, or you could also configure machine images to deploy on Amazon EC2.  The limiting factor will be technology (and licensing) restrictions.  If you had, for example, decided to use MySQL as a database (or any other data store), you would have more options.

Comment: Thanks for you immediate reply!! I am ok to move MySQL DB. I am entirely new to Cloud deployment. I would like to know is there any trial provider so i can deploy my application and test it out.